# Google script HTMLRequest - Post

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I try to authentificate myself in my account for DirectEnergie using google app script. 
When I put the request on POSTMAN with Chrome it works, but when I try to as followed, it returns me the HTML of the first page without the authentification.

```html
function getSumParr(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  url = "https://particuliers.direct-energie.com/mon-espace-client/?tx_deauthentification[login]=login&tx_deauthentification[password]=motdepasse&tx_deauthentification[form_valid]=1&tx_deauthentification[redirect_url]=  "
  var resultat = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(resultat);
}
```

When I follow the history of the request with postman, I have this : 
Response [303], Response [307]

Anybody has an idea on how to figure it out ?

Comment: The stack snippet is for code that is able to run directly on the question/answer, in other words, client-side code. As the question is about server-side code I removed the stack snippet.

Comment: Thanks ruben, I've learn something

Comment: You are welcome. Regarding the URL in your question, maybe the problem could be relate to the use of brackets. Does your URL requires brackets? If so, you should encode your URL.

Comment: Good idea, I was hoping it was this. I try to encode but it doesn't work neither. Thanks

Comment: Do you know if DirectEnergie has a documented API?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this tutorial about [GET and POST Requests in Google Apps Script](https://ctrlq.org/code/19871-get-post-requests-google-script):

> With Google Apps Script, you can easily create a Web App that serves HTML, JSON, XML or plain text output using the HTML service. When published as an app, the script gets a public URL that can be called using either GET or POST requests with parameters.

Here is their code snippet:

```
function testPOST() {

  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();

  var payload =
      {
        "name" : "labnol",
        "blog" : "ctrlq",
        "type" : "post",
      };

  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "POST",
        "payload" : payload,   
        "followRedirects" : true,
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
      };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  if (result.getResponseCode() == 200) {

    var params = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());

    Logger.log(params.name);
    Logger.log(params.blog);

  }

}
```

This sample also follows the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params) on how to make a request to fetch a URL using optional advanced parameters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rebot. I have seen this page and tried also but still the same result. 
Don't understand why in Postman it works and why in Ggscript not. Any other ideas ?